# CommandLink primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with p:commandLink

This is the link code

`<p:commandLink partialsubmit="true" id="c2aLink"
immediate="true" ajax="true" update="generalPanel" action="#{tabularbean.refresh}"/>`

The problem is when clicking this link it reload the page not just update the panel.

I want to only update the panel not reloading the whole page again

Note: i use javascript code to click this link

javascript code:

`render: function(options) {
var c2aLink = this.findElementWithIdLike(iframe.contentWindow,'c2aLink');
c2aLink.click();},`

```
findElementWithIdLike :function(wind,prefix) {
    return this.findChildWithIdLike2(wind.document.body, prefix);
},

findChildWithIdLike2 :function(node, prefix) {
    if (node && node.id && node.id.indexOf(prefix) >= 0) {
        //match found
        return node;
    }

    //no match, check child nodes
    for (var index = 0; index < node.childNodes.length; index++) {
        var child = node.childNodes[index];
        var childResult = this.findChildWithIdLike2(child, prefix);
        if (childResult) {
            return childResult;
        }
    }
},`
```

Comment: could you post the javascript code?

Comment: i updated the post to include the javascript code

Comment: When the button gets clicked does it submit an ajax request and then refresh more than you wanted or does a full submit occur?

Comment: If you post your exact use case here, I'm sure there'll be a cleaner way to trigger the ajax request than what you're trying currently. Also, you might want to confirm that the current situation is not the default for the `click()` function

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the element's `onclick` attribute handler, not the `click()` method.

Replace

```
c2aLink.click();
```

by

```
c2aLink.onclick();
```

The PrimeFaces ajax stuff is definied in `onclick` attribute.

Note that this all has nothing to do with JSF/PrimeFaces. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using the same HTML code as generated by JSF/PrimeFaces. In the future, it'd be more helpful if you play around with "plain" HTML in order to naildown/reproduce the problem instead of JSF/PrimeFaces. You will also have better chance in getting answers more soon if you asked the question in HTML/JavaScript context.

Answer (score 0):

`partialSubmit` will only work when the form/part of the form is submitted. You may use
**`oncomplete="submit()"`;** this is client side callback to execute when ajax request is completed.

Use :

```
process="@this" update="generalPanel"
```

Just in case you want to update form use:

```
update="@form"
```

Absolutely no need of javaScript code in this case. APIs like primefaces have inbuilt.